# Rudin RCA Question 3.8

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

The question goes as follows:

> If $g$ is a positive function on $(0,1)$ such that $g(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$, then there is a convex function $h$ on $(0,1)$ such that $h\leqslant g$ and $h(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$. True or false? Is the problem changed if $(0,1)$ is replaced by $(0,\infty)$ and $x\to 0$ by $x\to \infty$?

My initial thoughts regarding the $(0,1)$ part is to construct a sequence of points $\{x_n\}_{n\geqslant 1}$ that converges to $0$ such that $f\geqslant n$ on $(0,x_n)$. Then maybe we can define a sequence of convex functions $\{h_n\}$ using something related to $\chi_{(0,x_n)}$ and $g$ (maybe a piecewise linear one?). By Rudin's Exercise 3.1, the (pointwise) supremum of these functions would still be convex, so this seems to be a good candidate for the solution. So far I haven't been able to construct an explicit solution. Am I on the right track? Or am I missing some elegant solutions? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first claim is true. For positive constants $a$ and $\epsilon$, let $S_{a,\epsilon}$ be the function on $(0,1)$ which is zero on $[\epsilon, 1)$ and whose graph on $(0, \epsilon)$ matches the line segment from the point $(0, a)$ to the point $(\epsilon, 0)$. For each $n \ge 1$, there exists $x_n$ such that $g(x) > n$ on $(0, x_n)$. Then, $h_n = S_{n,x_n}$ is convex and bounded by $g$. Therefore $h = \sup_n h_n$ is also convex and bounded by $g$. Moreover, $h(x) > n/2$ on $(0, x_n/2)$, so $h(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$.

For the changed version, the statement is false. Suppose $h$ is convex and $h(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Then, there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $a < b$ and $h(a) < h(b)$. Let $m=(h(b)-h(a))/(b-a)$. If $x > 0$, then, by convexity, $(h(b+x) - h(b))/x \ge m$. Thus, $h(b+x) \ge h(b) + mx$. From this, we readily discover counterexamples, such as $g(x) = \sqrt x$ or, more generally, any function tending to infinity but whose rate of growth is sublinear.

Comment: Of course! $(0,a), a\in\mathbb{N}$ does the trick. Quite surprising result for the case $(0,\infty)$ to me, as I am relatively new to the material, but indeed intuitively convex functions grows "at least as fast as linear functions". Thank you very much!